# Simplifying CASE WHEN SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Im trying to improve the following CASE statement to calculate the difference only once. I do it to avoid negative numbers:

```
 SELECT (CASE WHEN ((SELECT 100 - (SELECT COUNT(CustomerId) FROM Customers)) > 0) 
         THEN       (SELECT 100 - (SELECT COUNT(CustomerId) FROM Customers)) 
         ELSE       (0) 
         END)
```

This not only looks stupid, but also is not thread-safe. I tried the following, but I get an error message "Invalid column name 'diff'."

```
 SELECT (CASE WHEN ((SELECT 100 - (SELECT COUNT(CustomerId) FROM Customers) as diff) > 0) 
         THEN  (diff) 
         ELSE  (0) 
         END)
```

How can this be simplified? Is there an in-built SQL function that already does this job?

**EDIT:** Sorry, forgot to mention that the select statement is inside of a view declaration, so I cant declare variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I follow your logic right, this should do it:

```
SELECT COALESCE ((SELECT 100 - COUNT(CustomerID)
FROM Customers
HAVING COUNT(CustomerID) < 100), 0)
```

*Slightly* more graceful.

If there was a row-based MAX() function, we could use that too.  Of course you could write one easily enough.

Comment: Thanks, that did it! I improved it even further `SELECT COALESCE ((SELECT 100 - COUNT(CustomerID) as diff FROM Customers HAVING diff < 100), 0)`

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @diff int
SELECT @diff = 100 - COUNT(*) FROM Customers

SELECT CASE WHEN @diff > 0 THEN diff           
            ELSE 0           
       END as Diff
```

Comment: Just because, I'd use SET instead of SELECT in that third statement, to make it clear that you aren't hitting the table a second time.  (Been fighting Transactions today...)

Comment: @Philip Kelley: without more context, it is not known whether the last select is returning results to caller...

Answer (score 1):

You could use a variable to start the result of the query so you don't have to execute it twice. For example:

```
DECLARE @CustomerCount INT
SELECT @CustomerCount = COUNT(CustomerId) FROM Customers
SELECT CASE WHEN (100 - @CustomerCount > 0) 
     THEN 100 - @CustomerCount
     ELSE (0) 
     END
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you only want to count once and you want to do it so it clearly shows what your logic is.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN cnt > 100 THEN 0
       ELSE 100 - cnt END AS diff
FROM (SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt
      FROM Customers) AS CustomerCnt
```